# How to read or fetch the Json array inside Json object

Tags: angular, typescript, api

In my angular application I have called the API and  I fetched the data of Json object.
And my question is how to read the Json array inside Json object.
And the json object I received is

```
{
"Drone": {
    "Droneid": 1001,
    "latlong": [
        {
            "lat": 12.989839,
            "lon": 80.198822
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.051832,
            "lon": 80.194480
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.038453,
            "lon": 80.227442
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.009018,
            "lon": 80.242550
        },
        {
            "lat": 12.976903,
            "lon": 80.237056
        },
        {
            "lat": 12.956829,
            "lon": 80.193107
        },
        {
            "lat": 12.980917,
            "lon": 80.150531
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.007680,
            "lon": 80.149158
        },
        {
            "lat": 13.043805,
            "lon": 80.154651
        }
    ]
}
}
```

An I have to call the latlong array from the above object.

My service function is

**Dashboard.service.ts**

```
export class DashboardService {
public Drones:any;
  latlong:any=[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {

mapping(token){
  let httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
    })
  };
    this.http.get(environment.apiurl +'/api/data/json', httpOptions).subscribe(  
    (dronesdt:any)=>{
      localStorage.setItem("dronesdt",JSON.stringify(dronesdt));
      console.log("Drones",JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dronesdt")));
} 
  )
}
```

**Dashboard.component.ts**

```
  constructor(private ds:DashboardService,private router: Router) { }
 Drones:any;
  Droneid:string;
  latlong:any=[];

  this.mapping();

mapping(){
this.drones=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dronesdt"));
console.log("Drones",this.drones)
}
```

*I have received the entire json object but I am not able to receive the array inside the object.
Can anyone help me regarding this reading the Json array inside object.*

Comment: What is the output of your console statements? Can you reproduce in a codesandbox or something? It solely depends on your API we can't say anything out of context.

Comment: The output of console is what I have mentioned in the above Json object.I have fetched the entire Json object but I have to read latlong array from the object.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do this:

**Dashboard.service.ts**

```js
export class DashboardService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {

  getDrones():Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get(environment.apiurl +'/api/data/json', httpOptions);
  } 
}
```

**Dashboard.component.ts**

```js
 latlong:any=[];

 constructor(private ds:DashboardService,private router: Router) { }
  
 ngOnInit(){
   this.ds.getDrones().subscribe( res => {
      this.latlong = res.Drone.latlong;
      // Other local storage setting here...
   });
 }
```